# ANDROID: Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

Tags: android, url, crash, inputstream, httpurlconnection

I want to fetch data from a web page cause i want to monitor some trains delay(up to 6), but the application crash on connect method when i do a new InputStream :\

here is the connect method

```
public class DataReader {

static URL url;
static HttpURLConnection hUC;
static InputStream inStream;
static BufferedReader br;
static String situation[];


public DataReader(int size) {
    situation = new String[size];
    initializeSituations(size);
}

private void initializeSituations(int size) { for (int i = 0; i < size; i ++) { situation[i] = "Not monitored";} }

public static void connect(int ind, String tNumb) throws IOException {
    url = new URL("http://mobile.viaggiatreno.it/vt_pax_internet/mobile/numero?lang=EN&numeroTreno=" + tNumb);
    hUC = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    inStream = new BufferedInputStream(hUC.getInputStream());
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream));
}

public static int setSituation(int ind) throws IOException {
    if (readTo("\t\t\t\t<!-- SITUAZIONE -->") == 0) {
        br.close();
        return 0;
    }

    skipLine();
    situation[ind] = readToBr();
    br.close();
    return 1;
    //1 = set done
    //0 = error
}
```

The connect method is called by this asyncTask inside onPreExecute method

```
public class ThreadUnit extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

int ind;
int j;

public ThreadUnit(int ind) {
    this.ind = ind;
    this.j = 0;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    //Toast.makeText(DataHolder.context, "on pre execute", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    DataHolder.progressBars[this.ind].setProgress(0);
    DataHolder.progressBars[this.ind].setMax(DataHolder.pTime[this.ind]);
    try {
        DataReader.connect(this.ind, DataHolder.getTrainNumber(this.ind));
        DataReader.setSituation(this.ind);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    for ( this.j = 0; this.j < DataHolder.pTime[this.ind]; this.j += 1000) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            publishProgress(j);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
          if (isCancelled())
            break;
        }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
    //Toast.makeText(DataHolder.context, "onProgressUpdate!" + progress[0].toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    DataHolder.progressBars[this.ind].setProgress(progress[0]);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    //Toast.makeText(DataHolder.context, "done!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    ThreadHive.restartUnit(this.ind);
    DataHolder.updateMainScreen(this.ind);
}

@Override
protected void onCancelled() {
    //Toast.makeText(DataHolder.context, "cancelled!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    DataHolder.progressBars[this.ind].setProgress(0);
}
```

}

Here is also the method starting the thread

```
    public void addTrain(View view) {

    if (trainNumber.getText().length() == 0){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Insert a train number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    }

    int selectedId = radioTime.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    radioTimeButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
    int pollingValue = Integer.parseInt(radioTimeButton.getHint().toString());
    int ind = getIntent().getIntExtra("index", 0);

    DataHolder.setTrainNumber(ind, trainNumber.getText().toString());
    DataHolder.set_tStatus(ind, randomStatus());
    DataHolder.set_pStatus(ind, true);
    DataHolder.set_pTime(ind, pollingValue);

    ThreadHive.executeUnit(ind);

    onOptionsItemSelected(null);
}
```

and this is the main declaring the 2 static classes and the thread class.

DataHolder: just have all the data shared between all activities and set changes on mainAcitivity (like the update of progress bars)

DataReader: set the connection and do some methods to get the values i want from the page.

ThreadHive: creates, kills and do all the stuff about the Threads

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final int TRAIN_SLOTS = 6;

TextView[] trainNumbersTW = new TextView[TRAIN_SLOTS];
TextView[] trainTimeTW = new TextView[TRAIN_SLOTS];
LinearLayout[] linearLayouts = new LinearLayout[TRAIN_SLOTS];
ProgressBar[] progressBars = new ProgressBar[TRAIN_SLOTS];
Button[] buttons = new Button[TRAIN_SLOTS];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_transparent);

    for (int i = 0; i < TRAIN_SLOTS; i++){
        String id = "textViewTN" + (i+1);
        int temp = getResources().getIdentifier(id, "id", getPackageName());
        trainNumbersTW[i] = (TextView)findViewById(temp);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < TRAIN_SLOTS; i++){
        String id = "textViewTT" + (i+1);
        int temp = getResources().getIdentifier(id, "id", getPackageName());
        trainTimeTW[i] = (TextView)findViewById(temp);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < TRAIN_SLOTS; i++){
        String id = "line" + (i+1);
        int temp = getResources().getIdentifier(id, "id", getPackageName());
        linearLayouts[i] = (LinearLayout) findViewById(temp);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < TRAIN_SLOTS; i++) {
        String id = "updateT" + (i + 1);
        int temp = getResources().getIdentifier(id, "id", getPackageName());
        buttons[i] = (Button) findViewById(temp);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < TRAIN_SLOTS; i++) {
        String id = "progressBar" + (i + 1);
        int temp = getResources().getIdentifier(id, "id", getPackageName());
        progressBars[i] = (ProgressBar) findViewById(temp);
    }
    new DataReader(TRAIN_SLOTS);
    new DataHolder(trainNumbersTW, trainTimeTW, progressBars, linearLayouts, buttons, this);
    new ThreadHive(TRAIN_SLOTS);
}

/**********_START_ACTIVITIES_**********/
public void startEditActivity(View v, int ind) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("index", ind);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void startSettingActivity(View v, int ind) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditTrainSettingsActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("index", ind);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void startPreferences(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditPreferences.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

/**********_MENU_**********/
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.item_notifications:
            if (item.isChecked()) {
                item.setChecked(false);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Notifications disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {
                item.setChecked(true);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Notifications enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return true;

        case R.id.item_preferences:
            startPreferences(getCurrentFocus());
            return true;

        case R.id.item_refresh:
            resetToDefault();
            ThreadHive.DestroyHive();
            DataHolder.updateAllMainScreen();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Refreshed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/**********_BUTTONS_CLICKED_**********/
public void pollingStatus(View view) {
    Button b = (Button)view;
    int ind = getIndexLine(view);

    if (DataHolder.pStatus[ind] == true) {
        if(DataHolder.tStatus[ind]!=-1) {
            DataHolder.set_tStatus(ind, 0);
            ThreadHive.killUnit(ind);
        }
        DataHolder.set_pStatus(ind, false);
        b.setText("STOP");

    }else{
        if(DataHolder.tStatus[ind]!=-1) {
            DataHolder.set_tStatus(ind, randomState());
            ThreadHive.executeUnit(ind);
        }
        DataHolder.set_pStatus(ind, true);
        b.setText("START");
    }
    DataHolder.updateMainScreen(ind);
}

public void editTrain(View view) {
    int ind = getIndexLine(view);

    if (DataHolder.tStatus[ind] == -1) {
        DataHolder.tStatus[ind] = randomState();
        startEditActivity(view, ind);
    }else
        startSettingActivity(view, ind);

    DataHolder.updateMainScreen(ind);
}
```

and this is the error track i get.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5210)
                                                                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21169)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5451)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                      Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                                                                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5210) 
                                                                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21169) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5451) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                                      Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
                                                                         at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1273)
                                                                         at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:431)
                                                                         at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
                                                                         at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
                                                                         at com.android.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29)
                                                                         at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:188)
                                                                         at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:157)
                                                                         at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:100)
                                                                         at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:358)
                                                                         at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:341)
                                                                         at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:331)
                                                                         at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:249)
                                                                         at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:437)
                                                                         at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:388)
                                                                         at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:231)
                                                                         at com.teocri.trainmonitor.DataReader.connect(DataReader.java:31)
                                                                         at com.teocri.trainmonitor.ThreadUnit.onPreExecute(ThreadUnit.java:25)
                                                                         at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:604)
                                                                         at com.teocri.trainmonitor.ThreadHive.executeUnit(ThreadHive.java:31)
                                                                         at com.teocri.trainmonitor.EditActivity.addTrain(EditActivity.java:58)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                                                                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5210) 
                                                                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21169) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5451) 
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Everything was working before i added the connect method so i suppose that's the problem but i have no idea how to fix it.

Thanks you very much for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/how-do-i-fix-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Comment: onPreExecute is obviosuly called from main thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have full memory in your device so thread can't allocate memory and crash

Comment: Oh thank you man !!! it worked :O the code was fine was only about free space on my device...

Answer (score 0):

See your logcat before posting a question here its saying

> android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

That means you are doing some network task on main thread. Find it and resolve it.

Comment: ok thank you, i'll look for it but it's strange cause i'm pretty sure i do network stuff only in DataReader class.

Comment: i checked my code and in my mainActivity there's no one call to DataReader.connect(...) or anything relate to that. I do the call on ThreadHive (static class to manage the 6 threads i use) to execute a particular thread, then the thread call the DataReader.connect(...) in it's onPreExecute, so i was wondering if that can cause the android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException ??

Comment: onPreExecute runs on Ui thread . Only doInBackground() runs on separate thread.